# Images in a multistateobject

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

I want to change the position of a picture located within a multistate object.

I have joined two rectangles (one of which contains a placed bitmap) to form a multistate object together. But now I can't address these rectangles as rectangles anymore, only as pageitems. So:

```
app.activeDocument.multiStateObjects[0].states[0].rectangles.length
```

gives 0.

while

```
app.activeDocument.multiStateObjects[0].states[0].pageItems.length
```

gives 1.

Since I can't address the picture frame as a rectangle anymore, I can't do anything with the picture it contains... (I would like to apply the fit function on it: `myFrame.fit(FitOptions.CONTENT_TO_FRAME)`, but then `myFrame` should be a rectangle, not just a `pageItem`)

Answer (score 1):

The `pageItem` is most likely a `group`. When you create a `multistateObject`, it creates groups for each state and these `groups` become the `parents` of the `pageItens` you had. So you should be able to access your rectangles like this:

```
app.activeDocument.multiStateObjects[0].states[0].groups[0].rectangles
```

Comment: Julien, tu es magnifique! This does the trick. Thank you very very much!